# conditional formatting in excel if two things happen on the same day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my excel sheet has three columns that I need to conditionally highlight based on date for a specific limited set of values.  if on the same day any of these code values show up for an id number, I need to conditionally format those cells or highlight them.
The column/field names are column "a" id#, Column "AA" Date, Column "AC" code.
the values of the codes that I need to check are 11213, 11214, 11203,11204,R3031, R3043, F1245
So if in my file (usually about 4000 records each), for the same ID number on the same day ANY of these codes show, I want to highlight.  Other codes can exist and these codes can appear on the same id on different days. BUT if this specific list of id's# show on the same day as each other, I need to know.
id#           Date             code

Answer (score 0):

Excel 365 has a new function, `UNIQUE()`, which you can use for filtering duplicates.

In order to solve your issue, you might go for a conditional formatting formula, based on this:

```
=COUNTA(Range)<>COUNTA(UNIQUE(Range))
```

When the count of non-empty cells equals the count of non-empty different cells, you know that all cells in your range are different. If not, you have duplicates somewhere.

I would advise you to start working with a helper column, where you can test this formula (try to get `TRUE` on the rows with duplicates) and once this works, you might try to use this as an input for conditional formatting.